# How to solve the following partial differrential equation(PDE)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The PDE is the following:
$$ω_ξ + \frac{1}{ξ}ω=f(ξ) \quad :(1)$$
where $ω=ω(ξ,n)$ and $ω,f,g \in \mathbb{C}^2$

My solution is:
$$(1) \Rightarrow ξ \frac{dω}{dξ} + \frac{dξ}{dξ}ω=ξ f(ξ) \Rightarrow \frac{d}{dξ}(ξ \cdot ω)=ξ f(ξ) \Rightarrow \int\frac{d}{dξ}(ξ \cdot ω)dξ=\int ξf(ξ)dξ +g(n)$$

So we have:
$$ξ \cdot ω=\int ξf(ξ)dξ +g(n) \Rightarrow ω=\frac{1}{ξ}\int ξf(ξ)dξ +\frac{1}{ξ}g(n)$$
$$\Rightarrow ω=\frac{1}{ξ}φ(ξ)+\frac{1}{ξ}g(n)$$

Is my solution correct ? Can I say that? $$φ(ξ)=\int ξf(ξ)dξ$$

Comment: Did you mean ODE

Comment: no it is partial

Comment: I don't see any derivatives with respect to $n$ though

Comment: Sal@yes you are right, so i can see this as ode.What do you think,is my solution correct or i miss something?

Comment: It is correct. Your equation, being first order and linear, is solveable via integrating factor. In this case the integrating factor was just $x$, as you found